# Is Sensitivity Analysis for Making Causal Inferences Only for Backdoor Adjustment?

Tags: causality, sensitivity-analysis

I am wondering if sensitivity analysis for causal inference is only applicable when doing backdoor adjustment/selecting on observables.

Conventionally, sensitivity analysis evaluates the threat of an unknown confounder to a causal estimate in observational studies. In studies where we select on the observables, this type of sensitivity analysis makes sense since adjusting for observable confounders is the adjustment method.

However, in front-door adjustment methods (instrumental variables, regression discontinuity, etc.) confounders are not incorporated into the adjustment method. As a result, any sensitivity analysis that seeks to quantify the damage a hypothetical unknown confounder would cause does not seem applicable.

Am I correct in this thinking? If so, are there alternative sensitivity analysis methods for front-door adjustment methods?